# Scrollbar doesn't start from the top of the page: waterfall header in Material Design Lite

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

The scrollbar of the page doesn't start from the top of the page with the "Waterfall header" - gets compact while scrolling - in Material Design Lite UI Kit.

I want it to start from the top of the page but I don't want to lose the "compactibility" of the header.

The codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XeNvGV

Here's the code of the header:

```html
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Uses a header that contracts as the page scrolls down. -->
<div class="demo-layout-waterfall mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header--waterfall">
    <!-- Top row, always visible -->
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <!-- Title -->
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-textfield--align-right">
        <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" for="waterfall-exp">
          <i class="material-icons">search</i>
        </label>
        <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
          <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="sample" id="waterfall-exp">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Bottom row, not visible on scroll -->
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <!-- Navigation -->
      <nav class="mdl-navigation">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <main class="mdl-layout__content">
    <div class="page-content">
      <!-- Your content goes here -->
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Little change in CSS :

```
.mdl-layout__content {

overflow-y: initial;
overflow-x: initial;

}
```

Or inherit, but just override the change made by Google.

Comment: I tried it. It makes the header "scrollable" and it removes the waterfall feature which compacts the header while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see.

The scrolling part is in the material.js :

```
/**
   * Handles scrolling on the content.
   *
   * @private
   */
MaterialLayout.prototype.contentScrollHandler_ = function () {
    if (this.header_.classList.contains(this.CssClasses_.IS_ANIMATING)) {
        return;
    }
    var headerVisible = !this.element_.classList.contains(this.CssClasses_.IS_SMALL_SCREEN) || this.element_.classList.contains(this.CssClasses_.FIXED_HEADER);
    if (this.content_.scrollTop > 0 && !this.header_.classList.contains(this.CssClasses_.IS_COMPACT)) {
        this.header_.classList.add(this.CssClasses_.CASTING_SHADOW);
        this.header_.classList.add(this.CssClasses_.IS_COMPACT);
        if (headerVisible) {
            this.header_.classList.add(this.CssClasses_.IS_ANIMATING);
        }
    } else if (this.content_.scrollTop <= 0 && this.header_.classList.contains(this.CssClasses_.IS_COMPACT)) {
        this.header_.classList.remove(this.CssClasses_.CASTING_SHADOW);
        this.header_.classList.remove(this.CssClasses_.IS_COMPACT);
        if (headerVisible) {
            this.header_.classList.add(this.CssClasses_.IS_ANIMATING);
        }
    }
};
```

I'm not a JS expert, so if it help you identify where to make the changes ...